# Adding deploy folders to the JBoss 5.1.0 classpath

Tags: jboss, classpath, configuration-files, jboss5.x

In JBoss 5.1.0 there are the following files:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/<INSTANCE>/conf/jboss-service.xml
<JBOSS_HOME>/<INSTANCE>/conf/bootstrap/profile.xml
```

Folders into which wars/ears/deployables can be dropped should be specified in the `profile.xml` file's `applicationURI` section (where `deploy` is specified by default). Other folders which contain resources for the shared classpath can be added as `<classpath codebase="..." />` entries to the `jboss-service.xml` file.

Folders added to the `profile.xml` file's `applicationURI` section are also automatically put on the classpath.

While there seems to be no obvious problem with folders being specified in both `jboss-service.xml` and `profile.xml` is there any underlying issue with this?